# Tangent Line From a Point on a Sphere and $y$-axis

Tags: spheres, tangent-line

Let's say I have a sphere,

$$100 = x^2+y^2 +z^2 $$

This indicates that the center of our sphere is at $$(0, 0, 0)$$ and we have a radius of $$radius = 10$$

I'm under the assumption that $$P = (1, 9, \sqrt{18})$$ is a point on the sphere, correct me if I'm wrong.

Let's say I have a point $P$ and $3$ axes -- how would I calculate the tangent line that passes through the $p$ and the $y$-axis?

Comment: $(0,5,5)$ is not a point of such sphere

Comment: You are right it is not. I will adjust haha. Not a math guy, comp sci guy :P one moment

Comment: I changed it :P Thanks for that haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach: Intersection of tangent plane to the sphere at P with Y axis, call it Q. Line that contains PQ.

The equation of the tangent plane is:

$$x+9y+\sqrt{18} z+D=0$$

And $$1+81+18+D=0$$

The plane is then
$$x+9y+\sqrt{18} z-100=0$$

And Q is $(0, 100/9,0)$

PQ is then $( -1,-9+100/9,-\sqrt{18})$

And the desired line is

$$P + \lambda PQ$$

That is to say:

\begin{align}
x&= 1-\lambda    \nonumber \\
y&= 9 +  \frac{19}{9} \lambda.  \nonumber \\
z&= \sqrt{18} -\sqrt{18} \lambda.  \nonumber 
\end{align}

which is the equation of the line in parametric coordinates.

In cartesian coordinates:

$$1-x=\frac{9}{19}(y-9) = \frac{\sqrt{18}-z}{\sqrt{18}}$$

Pictorially:

[image]

Comment: Okay, I'm not a mathematician by any standard. I have a couple of questions. I get that the line I'm looking for is on the tangent plane. The tangent plane calculated is `(0, 100/9, 0)`? Stupid question - I thought a plane had 2 axes that went forever, isn't `(0, 100/9, 0)` a single point? As well, I have no idea how to go from a 3d plane to a 2d line that intersects the Y axis...

Comment: or is Q the point that is on the Y axis that I want to intersect? Cuz that would make a hell of a lot more sense lol

Comment: Q is the intersection point of the tangent plane and the Y axis

Comment: What is lambda in this case?

Comment: Lambda is any real number

Comment: Ok, so we have the points P and PQ, and in 2D I would know how to calculate a line from that. But in 3D, no clue

Comment: The two points are P and Q. PQ is the segment that goes from P to Q and the equation of the line in R3 is the one provided. In parametric coordinates, we would have:

Comment: How did you calculate Q? Just kidding I found it

Comment: You've been a tremendous help! I'm sure I'll be asking a couple more math questions related to these topics in the coming days. Thank you!

Comment: Any time! BTW, I added a picture including the sphere, the tangent plane, the Y axis, and the line containing P and Q.

Answer (score 0):

Given C(0,0,0) the center of the sphere, A(1,9,$\sqrt {18}$) a point of the sphere and R(0,y1,0) the point of intersection of the line with the Y axis.
We can write a generic vectorial equation for the tangent line:

(x,y,z) = A + tk, k∈Z in which t is a directional vector of the tangent line

Since the tangent line is perpendicular to the sphere on A we have the vector: AC = A - C = (1,9,$\sqrt {18}$) that is perpendicular to the line t, which allow us to write the plane x + 9y + 9$\sqrt {18}$z = d  that has the tangent line, the point A and the point R.

Since A belongs to the plane:

1+9*9+$\sqrt {18}$ * $\sqrt {18}$ = d

<=> 1 + 81 + 18 = d

<=> 100 = d

The the equation of the plane is: x +9y + $\sqrt {18}$z = 100.

Since R belongs to the plane:

0 + 9y1 + 0 = 100

<=> 9y1 = 100

<=> y1 = $\frac{100}{9}$

Therefore R(0,$\frac{100}{9}$,0)

Now we can find the directional vector t using R and A (two points of the tangent line)

RA = A - R = (1, $\frac{-19}{9}$,$\sqrt{18}$)

Finally, having a point of the tangent line (point A or point R) and a vector (vector RA) we can find the vectorial equation of the tangent line:
(x,y,z) = (1,9,$\sqrt{18}$) + (1, $\frac{-19}{9}$,$\sqrt{18}$)k, k∈Z

You could also find the cartesian equation of the line:

(x,y,z) = (1,9,$\sqrt{18}$) + (1, $\frac{-19}{9}$,$\sqrt{18}$)k, k∈Z

<=> (x,y,z) = (1+k,9+$\frac{-19}{9}$k,$\sqrt{18}$+$\sqrt{18}$k), k∈Z

<=> $\begin{cases}
x = 1+k \\ 
y = 9+\frac{-19}{9}k \\ 
z = \sqrt{18}+\sqrt{18}k
\end{cases}
$
<=> $\begin{cases}
x-1 = k \\ 
\frac{y-9}{\frac{-19}{9}} = k \\ 
\frac{z-\sqrt{18}}{\sqrt{18}} = k
\end{cases}
$

<=> x-1 = 9*$\frac{9-y}{19}$ = $\frac{z-\sqrt{18}}{\sqrt{18}}$

Answer (score 0):

These lines can be constructed without explicitly constructing the tangent plane or computing its intersections with the coordinate axes. If you look straight down at the tangent plane, the coordinate axes will appear to be concurrent lines that pass through the given point. These projections of the coordinate axes are exactly the lines you seek.

You already know a point on each of these lines ($p$), so you just need to find direction vectors $d$ for them with which to construct a parameterization $p+td$ of the line, but those direction vectors are just the orthogonal projections of the unit coordinate vectors onto the tangent plane. These are equal to the orthogonal *rejections* from the tangent plane’s normal, which for a sphere is equal to the displacement vector of the point of tangency, and so, using a standard formula for projection, the three direction vectors are $$(1,0,0)-{p_x\over p\cdot p}p \\ (0,1,0)-{p_y\over p\cdot p}p \\ (0,0,1)-{p_z\over p\cdot p}p.$$